# vuetify.js.map: Source map error: SyntaxError

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

Im trying to study Laravel with VueJS using Homestead. I decided to use Vuetify in my study instead of Bootstrap by installing it through`npm`.

Here is my app.js:

```
import "material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import App from "./components/App.vue";
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";

Vue.use(Vuetify, VueRouter, axios, VueAxios);


const routes = [
    { path: "/", name: "Dashboard", component: ExampleComponent }
];

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: "history", routes: routes, linkExactActiveClass: "active" });
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount("#app");
```

But in my console log I'm getting this error:

> Source map error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at
>   line 1 column 1 of the JSON data Resource URL: http://xcy.dv/js/app.js
>   Source Map URL: vuetify.js.map

What am I missing here? I'm new to VueJS

Comment: 9 times out of 10 the problem with this particular source map error is that the source map url actually returns a `404` error page and if you inspect it you'll see it's HTML and not a source map.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy what do you mean? `vuetify.js.map` exist in `node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js.map` and I inspect the `.map` file, it contains `JSON` data. And i look through the compiled `app.js` this is the only line that says regarding the file: `//# sourceMappingURL=vuetify.js.map`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the help of Vuetify community, I found out that I need to include [`.sourceMaps()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#css-source-maps) in my `webpack.mix.js` like this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').sourceMaps();
```

It basically enable the source maps since it's disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update `webpack.mix.js` with

```
mix.webpackConfig({
   output: {
      chunkFilename: mix.inProduction() ? "js/prod/chunks/[name]?id=[chunkhash].js" : "js/dev/chunks/[name].js"
   },
   devtool: 'source-map' // Notice this
}).sourceMaps(); // And this

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```